# OneSignalServiceExtension failing when submitting to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I have added OneSignal as a Swift Package and set it up as it says on their website. Now when I build and submit to the App Store it comes back with these errors:

```
[!] Error uploading ipa file: 
 [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90685: CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.onesignal.OneSignal-Dynamic' under the iOS application 'MyApp.app'.
[Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90205: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MyApp.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles.
[Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90206: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MyApp.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.
[Transporter Error Output]: Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90685: CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.onesignal.OneSignal-Dynamic' under the iOS applicati\nERROR ITMS-90205: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MyApp.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNoti\nERROR ITMS-90206: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MyApp.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.
[Transporter Error Output]: The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

I've doubled checked that **Always embed Swift standard libraries** is set to `No` in the extension target, as so many answers on here say. It's set to `Yes` on the main app target. My run path for the extension says:

```
$(inherited)
@executable_path/Frameworks
@executable_path/../../Frameworks
```

How can I fix this?

UPDATE

It turns out that OneSignal is added as a Framework to the extension. However, because it was added via Swift Package Manager, it doesn't seem to be possible to not embed it! Anyone know a fix for that?

Comment: You definitely don't want to be using `com.onesignal.OneSignal-Dynamic` as a bundle ID (unless you work for onesignal). You should unzip the app file and see what it looks like.  It seems you may be including a whole other bundle inside your app bundle

Comment: I haven’t used that as a bundle ID! I’m not sure where it’s coming from tbh. I’ll try poking around in my app file and see if I can find anything

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay so it looks like it has added OneSignal as a framework in the extension. Is that not allowed? I could remove it from the Frameworks section of the extension. I think it had added it automatically

Comment: Update, that didn't work, because it defo needs the OneSignal framework in there to be able to build. Weirdly can build and run on the iPhone but not for production in the app store

Comment: Is it possible to not embed a Swift package? Doesn't seem possible!

Comment: The framework should only be added once (in your main target) and you should ensure that it is referenced by the extensions.  Don't make the framework part of the extension target

Comment: That’s what I tried but it fails to build if I don’t make it part of the extension

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the root of the issue is

`ERROR ITMS-90685: CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one > bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.onesignal.OneSignal-Dynamic' under the iOS application 'MyApp.app'.`

You can't use bundle identifiers of `com.onesignal.*`.

1. Verify that your *Bundle Identifier* does not contain `com.onesignal.*` or the string, `onesignal`.

[image: Taget ->> General ->> Bundle Identifier]

The next three errors are likely caused by misconfiguring the notification service extension. The one error of note,

`Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90685: CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.onesignal.OneSignal-Dynamic' under the iOS applicati\nERROR ITMS-90205: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MyApp.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNoti\nERROR ITMS-90206: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'MyApp.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'.`

Indicates that the notification service extension's bundle identifier is `com.onesignal.*`.

2. Verify that **OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension** is of the form `your.unique.identifier.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` where `unique` doesn't equal `onesignal`.

[image: a.b.c.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension]

Another detail about **OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension** is that the version must match the version of your app exactly. If there is a mismatch, copy the version from your app and use that as the notification service extension's version.

At the moment, I don't think Swift has anything to do with your errors. If my assumptions (numbered above) turn out to be false, this may be a more significant issue that warrants a new issue on GitHub.

Comment: After doing more digging, I think this may be an issue with using the Swift package manager to pull OneSignal. I found this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-XCFramework/issues/10 that looks very similar to yours.